# How to solve this error database looks to have been partially upgraded in CiviCRM

Tags: civievent, civimail, civicontribute, webform-civicrm, civireport

[image]

I Upgraded CiviCRM 4.6 to 4.7 latest version but when I try Import database using drush `$ drush civicrm-upgrade-db` this command that time showing this error. when I going to this path `http://example.org/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1` if anyone knows the solution of this issue please tell me. thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide more detail
1. Version from to
2. Procedure used to upgrade.
3. Why you reimported database

Answer (score 2):

You would be able to successfully upgrade following these steps:

1. Empty the civicrm database
2. Restore civicrm database from the backup that you had created before performing upgrade
3. Temporarily remove the paths for custom PHP/template files if you have through: Administer->System settings->Directories
4. Try upgrading to version 4.7 again
5. Restore the custom files paths if point 3 was applied

Hope this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest jumping on chat.civicrm.org to get support on it - but back up & try again is definitely a good step if you have a backup